# How can SOAP-based service can be seen as a special case of a REST-style service?

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, software-design

A quote from `Java Web Services: Up And Running, Second Edition` book :

> "At present, the distinction between the two flavours of web service is
>   not sharp,
>       because a SOAP-based service delivered over HTTP can be seen as a special case 
>       of a REST-style service;"

### How ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How?

I believe the writer's statement is incorrect.

## What is SOAP?

According to wikipedia:

> SOAP can form the foundation layer of a web services protocol stack,
> providing a basic messaging framework upon which web services can be
> built. This XML based protocol consists of three parts: an envelope,
> which defines what is in the message and how to process it, a set of
> encoding rules for expressing instances of application-defined
> datatypes, and a convention for representing procedure calls and
> responses. SOAP has three major characteristics: Extensibility
> (security and WS-routing are among the extensions under development),
> Neutrality (SOAP can be used over any transport protocol such as HTTP,
> SMTP, TCP, or JMS) and Independence (SOAP allows for any programming
> model).

As you can see, there really isn't anything in this description of SOAP that takes any ideological stance over what the structure of your API calls (url wise) must adhere to. Of course, soap uses XML, and XML can have a data structure that essentially works as the rule-set of your API call... thats cool.

In contrast, we have REST.

## What is REST?

According to wikipedia:

> The REST architectural style describes the following six constraints
> applied to the architecture, while leaving the implementation of the
> individual components free to design:
>
> - **Client–server:** Servers are not concerned with the user interface or user state, so that servers can be simpler and more scalable.
> - **Stateless:** The client–server communication is further constrained by no client context being stored on the server between requests.
> - **Cacheable:** Responses must, implicitly or explicitly, define themselves as cacheable, or not, to prevent clients reusing stale or inappropriate data in response to further requests.
> - **Layered system:** A client cannot ordinarily tell whether it is connected directly to the end server, or to an intermediary along the way. Intermediary servers may improve system scalability by enabling load-balancing and by providing shared caches.
> - **Code on demand (optional):** Servers can temporarily extend or customize the functionality of a client by the transfer of executable code.
> - **Uniform interface:** The uniform interface between clients and servers, discussed below, simplifies and decouples the architecture, which enables each part to evolve independently. (i.e. HTTP GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE)

## Comparison

In my mind, it shouldn't be described as SOAP vs REST, it should be RPC vs REST. RPC is remote procedural call, which basically means that every single functionality of your API gets 1 distinct API endpoint, and so on. so, REST can do with 1 url what RPC does with 7. SOAP is RPC (right?)

Yes, both are web services.

But saying that an RPC API is RESTful-ish because its transmitted over `HTTP` is hardly grounds to say they are similar... from the detailed information above, you can see that REST takes a much more ideological approach to the structure, transfer, purpose, scalability, and state of your service, whereas SOAP doesn't really talk about those things, and presumably the developer can choose to do, or not do, those things.

In conclusion, more context is needed for me to really understand what point the author was trying to make. An RPC API can be similar to REST if you make it do *RESTful* things.. but that is really circumstantial, isn't it?